Nginx how to block acces to all server sites by connect headers?
Масh connections from different ip (for example)
199.45.154.146 - - [23/Jun/2024:20:52:13 +0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CensysInspect/1.1; +https://about.censys.io/)"
206.168.34.54 - - [22/Jun/2024:01:31:41 +0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 117 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; CensysInspect/1.1; +https://about.censys.io/)"

i try
map $http_user_agent $blocked_user_agents {
    default 0;
    "~*CensysInspect" 1;
}
deny if $blocked_user_agents;

nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "deny" directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:27
i try
if ($http_user_agent ~* "censys") {
    return 403;
  }

nginx: [emerg] "if" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:22

While you can use the deny directive in an http block, it's mostly useful for IP addresses and CIDRs, there's no deny if directive with a variable check unfortunately. Your if block must be inside a location or server block, hence the emerg error.
You can create a separate file, called includes/block-ua.conf for example and drop the if/return block there, and include it from each server block in your configuration:
# includes/block-ua.conf
if ($http_user_agent ~* "censys") {
    return 403;
}

Your sites configurations:
server {
    server_name foo.org;
    include includes/block-ua.conf;
}

server {
    server_name bar.org;
    include includes/block-ua.conf;
}

That helps maintain the user-agent block list in one place.
